# Parsing xml file in python which contains multifasta BLAST result

Tags: python, xml, bioinformatics, biopython, blast

I'm trying to parse xml file which contains multifasta BLAST result - Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9-yqnpWUqL3eEhHWEkxc2ZVcnM/view?usp=sharing) - it's around 400kB in size. Program should return four sequence names. Every next result should be first after (contains the best alignment) "< Iteration_iter-num > n < Iteration_iter-num />", where n = 1,2,3,...

Like this:

```
< Iteration_iter-num >1< /Iteration_iter-num >

****Alignment****
sequence: gi|171864|gb|AAC04946.1| Yal011wp [Saccharomyces cerevisiae]

< Iteration_iter-num >2< /Iteration_iter-num >

****Alignment****
sequence: gi|330443384|ref|NP_009392.2| 

< Iteration_iter-num >3< /Iteration_iter-num >

****Alignment****
sequence: gi|6319310|ref|NP_009393.1|

< Iteration_iter-num >4< /Iteration_iter-num >

****Alignment****
sequence: gi|6319312|ref|NP_009395.1|
```

But in result my program returns this:

```
<Iteration_iter-num>1</Iteration_iter-num>
****Alignment****
sequence: gi|171864|gb|AAC04946.1| Yal011wp [Saccharomyces cerevisiae]

<Iteration_iter-num>2</Iteration_iter-num>
****Alignment****
sequence: gi|171864|gb|AAC04946.1| Yal011wp [Saccharomyces cerevisiae]

<Iteration_iter-num>3</Iteration_iter-num>
****Alignment****
sequence: gi|171864|gb|AAC04946.1| Yal011wp [Saccharomyces cerevisiae]

<Iteration_iter-num>4</Iteration_iter-num>
****Alignment****
sequence: gi|171864|gb|AAC04946.1| Yal011wp [Saccharomyces cerevisiae]
```

How to get to another BLASTA result from this xml file?

Here is my code:

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = open ("BLAST_left.xml", "r")
records = NCBIXML.parse(result)
item = next(records)

file = open("BLAST_left.xml")
page = file.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "xml")
num_xml_array = soup.find_all('Iteration_iter-num')
i = 0
for records in records:
    for itemm in num_xml_array:
        print (itemm)
        for alignment in item.alignments:
            for hsp in alignment.hsps:
                print("\n\n****Alignment****")
                print("sequence:", alignment.title)
            break
        itemm = num_xml_array[i+1]
    break
```

// I know my English isn't perfect, but I really don't know what to do and I don't have any person to ask for it, so I had chosen You :)

Answer (score 1):

I think Biopython is a better option here to parse the XML, no neet to use BeautifulSoup:

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML


result = open("BLAST_left.xml", "r")
records = NCBIXML.parse(result)

for i, record in enumerate(records):
    for align in record.alignments:
        print("Iteration {}".format(i))
        print(align.hit_id)
        break  # Breaking here gives you only the best HSP.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python in-build module xml.etree.ElementTree to parse the xml

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('BLAST_left.xml')
doc = tree.getroot()
for item in doc.find('BlastOutput_iterations'):
    print '< Iteration_iter-num >{0}< /Iteration_iter-num >'.format(item.find('Iteration_iter-num').text)
    print '** ** Alignment ** **'
    print 'sequence:{0}|{1}'.format(item.find('Iteration_hits/Hit/Hit_id').text, item.find('Iteration_hits/Hit/Hit_def').text)
```